# Apache redirect https non-www to https www (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache

I know question like this has been posted several times. But I am facing a unique problem and looking for help regarding that.
I want to redirect everything to https://www.example.com

I configured LAMP on Ubuntu 16 and installed Lets Encrypt SSL. I also configured redirection and following is the status:

1. http non-www and http www are getting properly redirected to https www
2. https non-www and https www are both getting reverse redirected to https non-www (instead of intended https www)

Following are my apache configs:

**1. 000-default-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ServerName www.example.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/getcreed.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/getcreed.com/privkey.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**2. 000-default.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


    </VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This makes all redirects to https://www. I am using my website for instance.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?itechplanetpc\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.itechplanetpc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ikelie Cyril. Where shall I add this? Adding this to .htaccess or 000-default-le-ssl.conf is not helping. 000-default.conf already has a redirection rule.

As http is getting properly redirected, I believe port 80 is working as expected.
But https versions are getting redirected to non-www so maybe something to do with port 443?

Comment: Add it to .htaccess in the project root directory